# How to have the drop down automatically updated (with jQuery) after successfully upload form (using ajax)

Tags: jquery, dropdown, auto-update

I have 2 forms:

```
Form 1 -> create strategy
Form 2 -> create project
```

Form 2 is using data which are uploaded into the database by the form 1.

The form 1 upload the database properly.

The form 2 display all the strategy already in the database.

What doesn't work (yet):

When I create a strategy and upload it into the database with the form 1, the strategy is not available in the drop-down menu in the form 2. I need to reload the page to see it.

Currently, Form 1 and Form 2 are using AJAX to upload and display all data.

In the beginning I was using `$(document).ready(function(){...}`. This method was not correct as I was loading the dropdown from the moment the document was loaded (and therefore before the form had been uploaded).

I tried with the following statement `$(document).click(function){...}` but I have the same issue.

I tried also to place the jQuery in a separated script (as I have several jQuery scripts under the `$(document).click(function(){...}` but the issue is the same.

Here is the jQuery code snippet:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("select#newProjectMarketStrategy").change(function(){
        var selectedMarketStrategy = $("#newProjectMarketStrategy option:selected").val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: './php/returnStrategy.php',
            data: {marketStrategy:selectedMarketStrategy}
        )}.done(function(data){
            $("#marketStrategyId").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know if I can have the dropdown updated after the form had been uploaded into the database without reloading the page.

The current code display the entry already in the database. The only problem, is when I upload new data in the database based on the form 1,

HTML markup:

```
<form>
     <select id="newProjectMarketStrategy" required>
          <option value="">Select Market Strategy</option>
          <?php foreach ($marketStrategy=marketStrategy() as $key => $value) {echo $marketStrategy[$key];} ?>
     </select>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php   // RETURN COUNTRY BASED ON REGION SELECTED
echo "<select id=\"newStrategyCountryId\">";
echo "<option value=\"N/A\">Not Applicable</option>\n";
if (ISSET($_POST["marketStrategy"])) {
    $marketStrategy = $_POST["marketStrategy"];
    if (($marketStrategy != '') || ($marketStrategy != 'N/A')) {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=workplan;charset=utf8', 'root','');
        $region_market_strategy=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM market_strategy WHERE market_strategy_id ='" . $marketStrategy . "'");
        while ($data = $region_market_strategy->fetch()) {
            $var=$data['strategy_id'];}
        $dbextract=$bdd->query("SELECT * FROM strategy WHERE strategy_id = '". $var . "'");
        while ($data = $dbextract -> fetch()) {
            if ($data['strategy_id'] == $var) {
            echo "<option value=\"" . $data['strategy_id'] ."\" selected>" . $data['strategy'] . "</option>\n";
            } else{echo "<option value=\"" . $data['strategy_id'] ."\">" . $data['strategy'] . "</option>\n";}
        }
    }
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: can you please provide HTML code and response from your call?

Comment: I will edit my question with the HTML code. What do you mean with "response from your call"?

Comment: It means the data you retrieve from the AJAX request, in other words the value of `data`. Also note you're missing a closing `'` on the `url` property

Comment: I added the `'`. Actually, my code works fine. I can display the list of the strategy already in the database. what doesn't work is the following scenario:
I will use the **form 1** to add a `new strategy` and I will go the **form 2** to create a `new project` (everything using jquery). The `new strategy` is not displayed yet in **form 2**. I need to reload (or refresh) the page and then I will see the `new strategy` in **form 2**.

Comment: It would be much simpler if you can provide output of that data, for example from Network. But problem might be that `echo "</select>";`, because I don't see any opening `<select>` tag

Comment: @Qubis741 Sorry, I missed one copy-paste from my code. Actually, I can upload in the database and I can display, the code itself works fine. The only problem is my drop-down list is not refreshed after I added a new strategy in the database. I think this is because I used the event: `$(document).ready(function(){...}` which mean the ajax will load the dropdown based on the value in the database when I open the page (or when I refresh the page).

Comment: Where's the element with id `marketStrategyId` that you're populating with the HTML returned from the AJAX request?

Comment: can you please provide whole javascript code?